# Using Django numeric variable in css

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a bootstrap progress bar to work, but I'm running into a problem. I want to get the progress bar width from a Django variable, I use the templates language for this. The problem is, HTML changes the float variable (i.e 32.54) to a string (i.e 32,54). I'm not sure why this happens (my guess is encoding) but the width attribute will not work if the variable is not a number.

To clarify, this is my code.

**Views.py:**

```
def details(request):
    estudio = request.GET.get('estudio', '')
    uni = request.GET.get('uni', '')
    campus = request.GET.get('campus', '')
    result = Titulaciones.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM tasas t INNER JOIN titulaciones tit on t.codigo_titulacion = tit.codigo_titulacion INNER JOIN impartida_en imp ON tit.codigo_titulacion = imp.codigo_titulacion INNER JOIN centros cent ON imp.codigo_centro = cent.codigo_centro WHERE cent.universidad = %s  and tit.nombre = %s and cent.campus =%s', [uni, estudio, campus]);
    return render(request, 'proyecto_uni/details.html', {'result':result})
```

(If I print here, the variable still shows as a number).

**details.html**:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% for foo in result %}
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab1" >General</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2">Asignaturas</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3">Resultados</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- TAB 1 --> 
  <div id="tab1">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">{{foo.nombre}}</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>Universidad:</h4>
        <p>{{ foo.universidad }}</p>
        <hr class="m-y-2">
        <h4>Campus:</h4>  
        <p>{{ foo.campus }}</p>
        <hr class="m-y-2">
        <h4>Descripción:</h4>
        <p>Aquí debería ir la descripción</p>
        <hr class="m-y-2">
        <h4>Nota de corte:</h4>
        <p>{{ foo.nota_corte }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- TAB 2 -->
  <div id="tab2">
    <p>tab2</p>
  </div>

  <!-- TAB 3 -->
  <div id="tab3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{foo.nombre}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: {{foo.rendimiento}}%">
            <span class="sr-only">{{foo.rendimiento}}% Complete (success)</span>
          <!-- The problem is right above, in the width style tag -->
          </div>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 2%">
            <span class="sr-only">22% Complete (warning)</span>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 1%">
            <span class="sr-only">1% Complete (danger)</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

I posted all the code to make it easier to understand, hope I didn't make it more confusing. Anyways, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django formats numbers according to your localization settings. You can turn localization off by using:

```
{% load l10n %}
{% localize off %}
    {{ foo.rendimiento }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

You can also unlocalize one single value:

```
{% load l10n %}
    {{foo.rendimiento|unlocalize}}
```

[Django format localization documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/)